# Can I use ColdFusion using CFWheels test cases (RocketUnit) with Jenkins?

Tags: coldfusion, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, coldfusion-8

I want to know if anyone out there has tried to using ColdFusion project using the CFWheels framework on Jenkins - Continuous integration server ?

I know Jenkins has support for MXUnit but if I use the CFWheels framework I would be using RocketUnit not MXUnit. Would there be any support for RocketUnit on Jenkins? or anything glue that might make the 2 work ?

Comment: Why don't you **try it** and find out? If you get stuck, come back with details of what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Yes, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cfwheels/zgeTzLm1IHs

Comment: @peter you can be constructive like Matt and provide a link instead of not being helpful. I've tried searching for rocketunit support but didn't find anything useful for support with Jenkins. Hopefully trying to find someone who might know.

Comment: @matt thanks for that link. So we have to convert the output of rocketunit to junit xml in order to integrate it with jenkins.

Comment: What part of asking for a _specific_ problem is not being helpful or constructive? I could have gone and searched the cfwheels mailing list for "jenkins" and posted the first result, but _so could you!_ I'm here to help people who have tried something and got stuck. If posters have not demonstrated they've made any effort, they'll either get ignored or they'll receive feedback on that.

Comment: If the question had stated _"I've tried searching for rocketunit support but didn't find anything useful for support with Jenkins"_ then it wouldn't have come across as lazy, and so I may have, for example, suggested a search for [cfwheels jenkins](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cfwheels+jenkins) instead, (where the first result appears to be a suitable tutorial).

Comment: It seems to me your just looking to make problems. There are many questions on stackoverflow I don't like, but I just ignore those. I believe my question is valid and can be answered. It was and I'm satisfied with the answer. If you don't like it, well I don't know what to tell you. Just ignore it or you can keep posting comments and wasting your time. I think you shouldn't waste your time with that.

Comment: @george_h: If the question was answered from your point of view, would you mind answering your own question so that it is actually obvious for other people that there is an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins supports CFWheels only through some plugins that convert the RocketUnit output to JUnit XML. As specified in the link here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cfwheels/zgeTzLm1IHs provided by @Matt Busche, we can integrate RocketUnit tests with Jenkins.